# long running time of stored proc execution in prod server

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I was trying to exec a stored proc in the prod server and it took around 3 hours to complete but while running in our development server, it took only 15-20 mins....is there anyway that i can find out wat was happening in the prod server?

Comment: Can you post the stored procedure?  Also, what is the difference in the table row sizes?  Usually in a development environment it'll be a fraction the size of production so that might also have something to do with it.

Comment: try to see the execution plan , and check for the indexes on both servers